# Is there any way to view a list of all recent tag wiki edits on a specific site?

Tags: support, edits, tag-wiki

I would like to monitor tag wiki edits on a specific SE site. Is there any way to view a list of all recent tag wiki edits on a specific site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you accept the list being up-to-date up to the last Sunday morning, [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/898633/recent-tag-wiki-edits) does the job:

[image]

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 100
  t.TagName, h.CreationDate, h.text, h.Comment, h.UserId AS [User Link]
  FROM PostHistory AS h
  INNER JOIN Tags AS t
    ON h.PostId = t.WikiPostId
  WHERE h.PostHistoryTypeId IN (2, 5) -- Initial Body, Edit Body
  ORDER BY h.CreationDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the 10k tools is the suggested edits page. ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits))

It shows all pending, approved, and rejected edits, and (when applicable), who approved or rejected them. There are also tabs for "controversial", "anonymous", and "improved" edits.

Comment: This one misses all tag edits made by high rep users with edit priviledge.

Comment: But I have access to moderation tools on some beta sites, most notable [linguistics.se]. Source is self-test.

Comment: @jknappen This must have changed within the past 3.5 years since my answer was posted. I'll hunt around a bit.